align like environment with arrows left and right
I'm looking for an environment that would allow me to align equations at the = sign while also allowing me to draw arrows from one line to another.
I found the environment "witharrows" but I can only add arrows on the right of the lines... I would like to have arrows both on the left and the right.
Here's an example with the witharrows environment :
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle,tikz=blue}

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
    Q &= (6x-5) (7-4x) - (4+2x)(7-4x) \\
    &= (7-4x) \left[(6x-5) - (4+2x)\right] \Arrow{\parbox{5cm}{signe $-$ devant des parenthèses, on change tous les signes à l'intérieur. }}\\
    &= (7-4x) \left[6x - 5 - 4 - 2x\right] \\
    &= (7-4x) \left[4x - 9\right] 
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}

and the end result :

Thank you in advance for your advices

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496844/1090

or this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/715350/arrows-from-one-line-to-another-in-align-environment
